# Can a webforms servercontrol be used with razor in mvc ( in 3 or 4 )?

Tags: webforms, razor, custom-server-controls

Can a webforms servercontrol be used with razor in mvc?

If there's different situations for different versions of mvc, that's fine.

Also, I believe that it is possible for usercontrols, but it's the server controls that i'm interested in.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the page model of an MVC and WebForms page are so different, it's very unlikely that you'll be able to make a server control work in MVC, especially Razor. You would probably have better luck trying to get one to work in WebForms classic view engine though.

With all that being said, you could always try and convert your control into some combination of a HTML helper and `RenderAction()` which would provide you with very similar functionality.

Overall I would not recommend even trying to use a custom control in MVC, there are much better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In general it will not work for WebForms server controls nor user controls (at least not ones called directly, you can still call an .ascx partial from a razor view). The Razor page model is incompatible with the WebForms control event lifecycle.